# How can I generate a Database diagram using Visual Studio Code automatically?

Tags: sql-server

How do I generate a Database diagram in Visual Studio Code automatically without having to actually create the tables one by one?If that's not possible what other app can I use for this?I'm a Mac user, so it would be helpful for any recommendations for apps that can do it automatically.

Comment: Tutorials and tool recommendations are off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use DataGrip on daily basis and it has the functionality that you want.

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Main issue is the license cost, but you have 30 days trial or you can apply for student license if you're gonna use for academic purposes.  It does have Mac support

You can check their documentation for it. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html